# swift call a func from another viewcontroller

Tags: swift, function, call, viewcontroller

I would like to call a func from another viewcontroller.

here with the code in pubListViewController: It is working fine.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationBarTitleImage(imageTitle: "IconTitle")
}

func navigationBarTitleImage(imageTitle: String) {
    // 1
    //        let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar

    // 2
    //        nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
    //        nav?.tintColor = UIColor.yellow

    // 3
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    // 4
    let image = UIImage(named: imageTitle)
    imageView.image = image

    // 5
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
}
```

now I try to call it in another viewcontroller as below, but it shows nothing.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    pubListViewController().navigationBarTitleImage(imageTitle: "addTitle")
}
```

Comment: You are using storyboard or not ?

Comment: what final o/p you want? your function is actually calling but it using instance `pubListViewController()`? so exactly you want ?

Comment: If you are creating new instance of the view controller and access its function. it won't reflect in your UI.

Comment: I just want to use the function from 1st view controller to set the title image of 2nd view controller instead of copying the function from 1st VC to 2nd VC. Am I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: Are you using segues ?

Comment: How are you navigating from first ViewController to second View Controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using notation like that `pubListViewController()` you call free empty initializer of `pubListViewController` which creates new instance of class `pubListViewController`, but you do already have one in your screens flow I bet, so all changes made by function you're calling later are being applied to invisible instance of `pubListViewController`.

To solve this problem you need a reference actually displaying instance of `pubListViewController` from your *another viewcontroller*

In `another viewcontroller` you can create a property of type `pubListViewController`, then before showing `another viewcontroller` set its property to `self`, and use that property from wherever you want in `another viewcontroller`.

```
class PubListViewController: UIViewController {
  func prepareForSegue(/**/){ // actually do that in the place where you showing your another viewcontroller, I don't know if you're using segues or not
    destinationViewController.parentPubListViewController = self
  }
}

class AnotherViewController: UIViewController {
  // declare property (weak and optional to avoid crashes or memory leaks if you forget to set that property from parent view controller
  weak var parentPubListViewController: PubListViewController?

  // use it anywhere you need
  parentPubListViewController?.navigationBarTitleImage(imageTitle: "addTitle")
}
```